# Proving that $\sup (A + B) = \sup (A) + \sup (B)$ through two contradictions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

There are certainly other posts on this website asking for help proving that $\sup (A + B) = \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. I would like to ask whether my proof, which I haven't seen elsewhere on this site after a brief search, is valid.

**Exercise:**

For nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$, prove that $\sup (A + B) = \sup (A) + \sup (B)$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $\sup (A + B) > \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. Then there exist $a \in A, b \in B$ such that $a + b > \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. Since we know that we must have $a \leq \sup (A)$ and $b \leq \sup (B)$, we see that this is not possible.

Now suppose that $\sup (A + B) < \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. That means that, for all $a \in A, b \in B$, we must have $a + b \leq \sup (A + B) < \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. However, let $A = B = [0, 1]$ to see that this clearly cannot hold, so we conclude that  $\sup (A + B) = \sup (A) + \sup (B)$ as desired.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, you can't fix them.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm not sure I understand the objection. It's a counterexample.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something really obvious, it's a counterexample because it implies that $2 < 2$, which is the contradiction.

Comment: You're right that $\sup([0,1]+[0,1]) = \sup[0,2] = 2$, and that $\sup[0,1]+\sup[0,1] = 2$, so yes, if you assume $\sup([0,1]+[0,1]) < \sup[0,1]+\sup[0,1]$, it means $2<2$, which is a contradiction. But this is NOT what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Try and use your proof explicitly in the case that $A = B = [-2, -1]$. (Of course, there's a limit to how explicit you can be with a proof by contradiction, but hopefully it will make the error clear.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the statement

> $P$ : for all $A,B\subset \Bbb{R}$ which are non-empty and bounded above, $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A)+ \sup(B)$.

Its negation is

> $\neg P$ :  There exist $A,B\subset \Bbb{R}$ which are non-empty and bounded above, such that $\sup(A+B) \neq \sup(A)+ \sup(B)$.

You're trying to prove that $P$ is true by method of contradiction. What this means is that you have to assume the negation $\neg P$ is true, and then show that you arrive at a contradiction (a false statement).

Ok, so let's suppose that $\neg P$ is true: so there exist $A,B\subset \Bbb{R}$ which are non-empty and bounded above, such that $\sup(A+B) \neq \sup(A)+ \sup(B)$. **Now, choose such sets $A,B$** (and we have to keep them fixed throughout the remainder of the discussion). Now, there are two possibilities.

---

**Case $1$:** $\sup(A+B) > \sup A + \sup B$.

You wrote

> Suppose that $\sup (A + B) > \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. Then there exist $a \in A, b \in B$ such that $a + b > \sup (A) + \sup (B)$. Since we know that we must have $a \leq \sup (A)$ and $b \leq \sup (B)$, we see that this is not possible.

This is correct. You have shown that by assuming the false hypothesis of Case $1$, we arrive at a false statement.

---

**Case $2$: $\sup (A+B) < \sup A + \sup B$**.

Now you say take $A=B=[0,1]$. This is logically meaningless, because the $A$ and $B$ have already been fixed in the beginning of this discussion (we fixed the sets $A,B$ above, see the bold statement). You do not know that the $A,B$ which come from your hypothesis of $\neg P$, "there exist $A,B$..." are equal to $[0,1]$.

You can't change things in the middle of a discussion. So, really all you have done in your final paragraph is say that

> It is not true that $\sup([0,1]+ [0,1]) < \sup[0,1] + \sup [0,1]$.

which is not at all what was required to complete the proof by contradiction (just to reiterate, you have to show that for the "unknown" $A,B$ from the beginning, whose existence you already know of, that they cannot actually satisfy $\sup(A+B)< \sup(A)+\sup(B)$).

Comment: Thorough. Thank you. Explicitly formulating $P$ and $/neg P$ helps to clarify my error. Now I must attempt to salvage my proof...

Comment: @Novice and if I may offer some suggestion: try to avoid proofs by contradiction whenever possible, because very often a proof by contradiction just adds more complexity (and sometimes length) to an otherwise simple direct proof (like in this case, a direct proof is very obvious). This is of course entirely subjective.